# No classes specified

Tags: java, netbeans, java-native-interface

i have been following the tutorial of JNI in netbeans , i have encountered the following problem.

Please help me to solve these

```
C:\Users\avijapur\Documents\NetBeansProjects\HelloWorld>"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin\javah.exe" -o HelloWorldNative.h -jni -classpath  "C:\Users\avijapur\Documents\NetBeansProjects\HelloWorld\build\classes\helloworld\"HelloWorld.main"
Error: no classes specified

C:\Users\avijapur\Documents\NetBeansProjects\HelloWorld>
```

Comment: Try `$>javah -o HelloWorldNative.h -cp "C:\Users\avij
apur\Documents\NetBeansProjects\HelloWorld\build\classes" helloworld.Helloworld`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should specefy class in command line like

```
javah.exe -o HelloWorldNative.h -jni -classpath  "C:\Users\avijapur\Documents\NetBeansProjects\HelloWorld\build\classes" helloworld.HelloWorld
```